# Access ec2 instaces in AWS with private hostname from remote machine in a openvpn network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hostname, openvpn

I have several `ec2 instances` in a public subnet in `AWS vpc`. One of the instaces is `OpenVpn`. when I am connected to openvpn, theoritcally my remote machine is also in the same network. (my understanding: OpenVpn has a `elastic IP` and my machine IP also changes to the same one on the openvp). I am only able to access the other instances from my web browser with their public hostname. Why I can not access them from my machine with their private hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to the OpenVPN instance you need to ensure that there is routing from the OpenVPN connection to your wider VPC network.

[This blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/awsmarketplace/setting-up-openvpn-access-server-in-amazon-vpc/) by Amazon explains how to setup the VPN to allow this routing to be added.

Comment: yes I have that setting, but it doesn' work anyways.

Comment: Not at all. e.g. this is one private DNS for ec2: ip-10-0-0-120.eu-central-3.compute.internal and here is the public one: ec2-XXXX.eu-central-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8080. Port 8080 is open. I can access only with the public name not the private name. I want to access with private name, then I can release the estatic IP.

Comment: Can you connect to the private IP? And do your security groups reference private access now (using internal CIDR ranges rather than public ones).

Comment: In inbound rouls for the ec2, I added that CIDR to the source for 8080 port. Now I can access it only with the private 10.0.0.120:8080 but not with the private hostname.

Comment: That will be a DNS resolution issue, you can update configuration on your OpenVPN server (https://medium.com/@dusansusic/setting-up-openvpn-on-aws-8f6a319ee850)